# Is there a way to make webpage update on reload

Tags: php, laravel, web, web-development-server

I am working on a web application using Laravel 8. Whenever I make any changes, they do not reflect immediately. I have to clear the views

```
php artisan view:clear
```

and cache

```
php artisan cache:clear
```

and also force hard refresh by simultaneously pressing **Command** + **Control** + **R** severally before the changes effect. I have tried disabling cache on my browser and even checking the **Update on reload** under the **Application** tab in Google Chrome. I have also turned set `CACHE_DRIVER=none` in .env file. I would like to know whether there is a work around my issue because it's interfering with my effectiveness.

Comment: What does your `.env` file look like? How do you serve your pages?

Answer (score 0):

It may be worth noting that if you run "php artisan optimize" it will clear everything for you. Not sure if you are running this on your local or production, but it is worth running when you deploy new code to production.

Comment: `php artisan optimize` is deprecated since 5.5 and was removed in 5.6

Comment: Thanks for mentioning this, I have it running in my deploy script and it still seems to execute on the latest version of laravel, but I dont see it in the documentation so I will have to make that update.